# can not hook up asp server side control for javascript function

Tags: asp.net

Environment: .NET 2.0, visual studio 2005

in aspx markup, set a control like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="E287" runat="server"  />
```

in code behind, hook up event to a javascript func in Page_Load event like:

```
Me.E287.Attributes.Add("OnCheckedChanged", "javascript:alert(123);")
```

then test the page in browser, and click on the checkbox, no response. check the source, it is:

```
<span OnCheckedChanged="javascript:alert();"><input id="E287" type="checkbox" name="E287" /></span>
```

can't understand.

If change aspx markup like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="E287" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="javascript:alert(123);" />
```

will get error

BC30456: 'javascript' is not a member of 'ASP.MyPage_aspx'.

Really confused. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see the rendered control the javascript go to the span (label), to add it to the input/check box you need to use the [InputAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.inputattributes.aspx). Also on the client side you need to use the `onchange` or the `onclick` to get the results you looking for.

```
E287.InputAttributes
```

so it will be

```
Me.E287.InputAttributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:alert('123');")
```

Thats because the check box use 2 controls to render, one span and one input, so with your code you add on the text the script and not on check box.
There also the [LabelAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.labelattributes.aspx). Here the Attributes are go to the span, because span is parent of input.

```
 E287.LabelAttributes
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code from your code-behind:

```
Me.E287.Attributes.Add("OnCheckedChanged", "javascript:alert(123);")
```

`OnCheckedChanged` is not a client-side (JavaScript) event for a checkbox.  You need to change this to `onclick`.  This would explain why this event handler isn't firing.

With your second line of code of wiring up an event:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="E287" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="javascript:alert(123);" />
```

You're trying to assign a server-side event handler for the checkbox being checked to a method named "javascript:alert(123)" in your code-behind...which doesn't exist.

I would suggest you change your first attempt to wire up the event (using Attributes.Add) to use the `onclick` event instead:

```
Me.E287.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:alert(123);")
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a javascript event handler to the client side from the server side, try this:

```
Me.E287.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert(123);")
```

On the other hand, if you're trying to add a server side event handler, it should look something like this:

```
AddHandler E287.CheckedChanged, AddressOf E287_CheckedChanged
```

and of course you'd have to implement the `E287_CheckedChanged` event handler method.